# Unable to save file with ASP.NET FileUpload - access denied

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, access-denied

the below code is use for my website to insert photos, On my compouter, i can insert pics but when i transfer it to the remote machine, i get error message. Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub dvPictureInsert_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles dvPictureInsert.ItemInserted

    'If the record was successfully inserted, save the picture
    If e.AffectedRows > 0 Then

        'Determine the maximum pictureID for this user
        Dim results As DataView = CType(maxPictureIDDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        Dim pictureIDJustAdded As Integer = CType(results(0)(0), Integer)
        'Reference the FileUpload control
        Dim imageUpload As FileUpload = CType(dvPictureInsert.FindControl("imageUpload"), FileUpload)

        If imageUpload.HasFile Then
            Dim baseDirectory As String = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/")
            imageUpload.SaveAs(baseDirectory & pictureIDJustAdded & ".jpg")
        End If
```

Here is the error message:

> Server Error in '/please-god'
>   Application. Access to the path
>   'D:\Hosting\4423045\html\please-god\UploadedImages\3.jpg'
>   is denied. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   'D:\Hosting\4423045\html\please-god\UploadedImages\3.jpg'
>   is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will
>   be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 21:             If
>   imageUpload.HasFile Then Line 22:
>   Dim baseDirectory As String =
>   Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/")
>   Line 23:
>   imageUpload.SaveAs(baseDirectory &
>   pictureIDJustAdded & ".jpg") Line 24: 
>   End If Line 25:         End If Source
>   File:
>   D:\Hosting\4423045\html\please-god\PhotoAdmin\Default.aspx.vb
>   Line: 23
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   to the path
>   'D:\Hosting\4423045\html\please-god\UploadedImages\3.jpg'
>   is denied.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +7715167    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
>   Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +1162
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   +61    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode) +55
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String
>   filename) +99
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.SaveAs(String
>   filename) +23
>   PhotoAdmin_Default.dvPictureInsert_ItemInserted(Object
>   sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs
>   e) in
>   D:\Hosting\4423045\html\please-god\PhotoAdmin\Default.aspx.vb:23
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnItemInserted(DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs
>   e) +108
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleInsertCallback(Int32
>   affectedRows, Exception ex) +69
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary
>   values,
>   DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) +134
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleInsert(String
>   commandArg, Boolean causesValidation)
>   +274    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs
>   e, Boolean causesValidation, String
>   validationGroup) +676
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +113
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs
>   e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +135
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net FileUpload control problem: access to directory is denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863066/asp-net-fileupload-control-problem-access-to-directory-is-denied)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure the IIS or the server running the website has permission to write to that directory.
You could do this by selecting that folder -> Properties-> Security tab.

If that didn't help, you could recheck in the event log to find out with which account it tried to access it.

You might also wanna read [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1141587.aspx#1838319) post too.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have the App Pool set to a user with the correct rights, if you have impersonation turned on in your web.config then you will get this error.

Deleting this line from your web.config will turn off impersonation.

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I was having the same problem, I tested it locally and on live server as well but the same error was making me frustrated. Then I decided to critically review my `code` so that I can figure out what was causing the problem. And there the problem was, I was not specifying a filename in the fileupload `SaveAs()` method. I know the op is specifying a proper path but it could happen to someone else in future maybe.

How my code looked before: 
`fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath($"{basedir}"));`

How it looks now:
`fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath($"{basedir}/{fileupload.FileName}"));`